# Android - Firebase one to one user chat with Reciever Service

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to develop an app that will allow the user to interact with each other by means of Firebase messaging but the problem is that:

---

Tutorials and Open source projects only can be used when the activity is running:
For example, [This GitHub Project](https://github.com/firebase/AndroidChat) and [This StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43099915/android-firebase-one-to-one-chat-application) are also such type.

---

Please help me to get the solution to the problem that chat app can be used when is the app is not running with service or receiver or whatever you can suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when using firebase messaging, you don't want to use any external service because the class `FirebaseMessagingService ()` will do all those things for you.You just need to extend that class and it'll run on the background without the needing of your app to be run..

refer this for more info: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive